# Creating wine shortcuts on 15.10: how to hide from desktop but not from launcher?

Tags: unity, wine, shortcuts

So I followed a previous answer to successfully create a shortcut to a Wine application. I want to hide the desktop icon but still show the launcher icon. I deleted the my-app.desktop from the Desktop but that also deleted my launcher icon.

Any ideas how it can be done? thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you successfully created a launcher (`.desktop` file), the difficult part was already done :).

What you still needed to do was to move the launcher to `~/.local/share/applications` (`~` stands for your home directory). Then you *might* have to log out/in, but then the launcher will show up in Dash if the launcher is valid.

#### Explanation

Dash by default looks into both `/usr/share/applications` and `~/.local/share/applications` for valid launchers. The first one is for *globally* installed applications, the latter for local ones, or for local versions (with personal options) of the globally installed launchers.

Since `Wine` applications are (locally) installed in `~/.wine`, you should have your launcher in `~/.local/share/applications` by definition.

#### Additional information

Not really related to this question, but still good to know:
If an application's launcher exists in both `~/.local/share/applications` and `/usr/share/applications`, the first (local) one "overrules" the global one.